# Open shapefile in ArcGIS Runtime WPF SDK as Graphics/Feature layer

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-runtime

I Googled and followed [this tutorial](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=953a530ada30477d95cc69e788268bc9) and figured out how to import Shape files and Rasters into Runtime.

However, it seems most of the functionality uses a FeatureLayer/GraphicLayer instead an ArcGISLocalDynamicMapServiceLayer that the sample uses.

My question is if there is a way I can import the shapefile as a graphics layer or if I can somehow cast my ArcGISLocalDynamicMapServiceLayer as a Graphics layer because shapefile is essentially the same as a shapefile.

An example is I'm trying to use the FeatureDataGrid() to show the attribute table of my shapefile, but I can't since it requires a graphics layer, not an ArcGISLocalDynamicMapServiceLayer.